# How do i create a public ledger using blockchain for my application?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, blockchain, distributed

I'm developing a nodejs application and trying to integrate blockchain in it. Here in my application, I want to create a blockchain where only the server (my app) can create blocks. The blockchain is public and anyone can view it. I just need a simple way to store this blockchain publically and everyone has the read permission.

With my limited knowledge, I have created a system using node and MongoDB. where each block is stored as a document in db. using an api anyone can view the database, which didn't work.

Which backend technology should i use to get this done? Which specific npm modules should into?

Comment: "using an api anyone can view the database, which didn't work" **Why** would that not work?

Comment: First of all, i need a better storage solution which is synchronous, and sequential. using mongodb wasn't great because, when multiple requests comes in two blocks are linked to one parent block thus creating a branch instead of chaining. I want it to store in a decentralized platform.

Comment: Why would it create chains if you are the only one who can create blocks? Why do you want to use blockchain if you are centralizing it, the whole point of blockchain is decentralization.

Comment: @JBaczuk I just want my data (file hashes) publicly accessible, many suggested me blockchain (public ledger concept will help) correct me if I'm wrong. If blockchain is not what I'm looking for what should i use. thanks in advance.

Comment: Just make an open api and website to make that information publicly accessible. Blockchain is for decentralized consensus and way overkill for what you need.

Comment: @Susmith I think you really want to ask a different question, which is about your synchronization problem (i.e. two operations come in at the same time, and you want to order them properly). That doesn't require a blockchain at all. That's just a standard database synchronization issue. I suggest closing this question and opening a question about the underlying problem. Why do you even need to store it in a decentralized way; why not just have a server? That's the kind of thing to include in the question. But you definitely don't need blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of blockchain Public Blockchain, Private Blockchain and Consortium Blockchain. What you want is the Consortium Blockchain in which you can have a Control on blockchain and it is semi decentralised.

To interact with the blockchain to Show all the data you have to make the distributted application and use the Web3 Libraray to interact with blockchain.

So all your data can be Access through web3 library api and you Show it to your app. Through that anyone can see the data publicly.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what im looking for. Is there any popular services or app use this technology.

Comment: For the start i would say to create loca lblockchain and use Truffle for developing application using angularjs https://truffleframework.com/